# K8s cluster deletion doesn't remove the DNS entries from Managed zone on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, kops, google-cloud-dns

I ran following command to delete the cluster :
`kops delete cluster "clustername" --yes`

Post deletion, I can still see DNS entries in managed zone (created using Cloud DNS service) on GCP. Is it a known issue ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, so it's not mentioned on the [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/tutorial/gce.md) that it will delete the Zone as AWS so you can address this to the GCE github team if this is expected or not

Answer (score 0):

The command line `kops delete cluster "clustername" --yes` only delete the cluster that's it.

According the the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/tutorial/gce.md) and the output of the `kops delete cluster "clustername" it doesn't show any DNS entries or managed zone.

The type of resources that will be delete are :

- Address.
- Disk.
- ForwardingRule.
- Instance.
- InstanceGroupManager.
- InstanceTemplate.
- Route.
- TargetPool.

Comment: just wanted to clarify, I'm not talking about GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). That's a managed Kubernetes service offered by Google, to create the k8s cluster.   KOPS has nothing to do with GKE. It's an open source tooling to create, manage, upgrade and maintain production grade K8s cluster on GCE (Google Comoute Engine).   Moroever, I'm referring to automatic deleteion of DNS records that are  created by KOPS in managed zone.